# What are the gravitational assist effects on the inclination of a probe's trajectory, from passing by Jupiter at different latitudes?

Tags: gravity-assist, flyby, jupiter

A flyby probe at Jupiter gets its inclination, relative to the ecliptic, changed if it passes above or below Jupiter's equator. How sensitive is a trajectory to this effect?

I imagine that there could exist a function which approximately describes the change in a flyby probe's trajectory given the perijove latitude, the altitude and whether on the leading or trailing side of Jupiter's orbit around the Sun. *(I don't request exact calculations, just some hand which waves a ball in the park, or however the sayings go).* Would a polar passage at Jupiter throw a probe into a trajectory perpendicular to the ecliptic?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, Jupiter can make a trajectory perpendicular to the ecliptic, which is exactly what it did for [Ulysses](http://solarsystem.nasa.gov/missions/ulysses), which observed the poles of the Sun:

[image: Ulysses trajectory]

The function is just vector addition. It depends on the $V_\infty$ with respect to Jupiter and the flyby distance, from which you get a change in direction in the plane of the trajectory relative to Jupiter, which is a $\Delta V$ vector. You change from the Jupiter-centered plane to to the Sun-centered frame to get the $\Delta V$ vector in that frame and add that to the velocity vector of the spacecraft in that frame before the swing-by. Then the new plane formed by that vector and the Sun is the plane of the new orbit.

See [this reference](http://ccar.colorado.edu/asen5050/projects/projects_2012/reid/) for the calculations.

Comment: I just got a new idea for something to try in KSP, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a good way to visualize this  [image: pioneer 11 trajectory error] Notice pioneer 11 did not meet its aimpoint plan so the Pioneer 11 solid third stage is most likely is in a Ulyssis solar polar orbit of some kind

Comment: How does this graph work? I understand the colored dots are the target points. But how can you infer their post-encounter orbits? do you draw a line from the target point through Jupiter's center, to a point opposite the target point? Also, can you link to the source of this graph?